# What can I use as a gateway game for crayon rail games?

Tags: crayon-rail-games

I like the crayon rail games.  I've played a lot of Iron Dragon, some EuroRails, and a smattering of others.  I'd like to introduce  acquaintances who aren't already experienced gamers to them (doing some boardgame evangelism here).  But these games are rather longer than most gateway games.  At an hour per player (on average, in my group) and not working very well with fewer than four players, these games don't fit neatly in a weeknight after-dinner gathering, even considering [How to speed up a game of Empire Builder?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/4268/1315).  (The techniques there work better for experienced players, and they don't make the large difference I'm looking for.)

Is there either a faster member of this category of game or a *tested* set of rules variants that produces a satisfying game in the two-hour range for four or more players?  I *think* a smaller map + a recalculated end-game trigger would do it; a smaller map means fewer options, more route contention, and quicker deliveries.  But you still want the game to progress through all the stages (initial build, expansion, money engine), so I don't know if blocking off regions on an existing map (and doing something to be determined with affected route cards) can work.

What can I use for a shorter gateway to crayon rail games?

Comment: I see an off-topic ("not about board games") close vote and am confused.  Could somebody explain?  From the on-topic help and a look at the other questions on this tag, it looks on-topic to me.  But I'm not super-active here and am not up on meta discussions.

Comment: British Rails looks as if it might have a smaller map than Empire Builder. I've never played it. Unfortunately Empire Builder appears to be the gateway game. It's certainly faster than either Iron Dragon or Martian Rails. Have you considered switching your allegiance to Ticket to Ride? :)

Comment: The poor reception is because this looks like a game recommendation question (I guess you can only see the generic off-topic "This question does not appear to be about board or card games" rather than the specific "Questions asking for game recommendations are off-topic." reason that the close-voters actually selected). See https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/1926

Comment: @Monica Cellio I just learned of the existence of Empire Express, which came out in 2012, and which you should have stumbled across when scouring the internet.

Comment: Thanks @SteveB; didn't know about that one.  (I somehow wrote Empire Builder in my question when I really meant EuroRails.  I've only played EB once and didn't think to start a search there.)

Comment: Thanks @goldPseudo.  I thought a question aimed at introducing people to a narrowly-scoped class of games would be welcome.  (An open-ended "what should I play?" opinion survey would obviously be a bad fit, and seems to be what that meta post is worried about, but the problem to solve here is pretty specific.)  I got my answer in a comment, so I'm not going to try to figure out how to do the wordsmithing dance to get this reopened now.

Comment: I'm pretty disappointed by how we handled this. Yeah, we've deemed recommendation questions off-topic, but the goal of that was to put a stop to really broad, opinion-based questions. This sort of well-defined, well-written question is the collateral damage of that policy. The least we could do is try to help the OP edit, rather than simply closing.

Comment: The point of closing is to prevent low-quality answers being posted while such edits are made. However, you allowed comments which are really answers to remain, which have led to MonicaCellio declining to make further effort to get the question reopened, instead of removing them. Is it any wonder people don't bother following process and help edit or *"ask for more information or suggest improvements"* when that's the reaction of a moderator? @Cascabel

Comment: @Nij All but one of the close votes were before that comment, and they were all before I could've possibly deleted it. Moreover, a single comment left standing (in this case because I valued preserving context more than I valued absolute enforcement) is absolutely not a justification for our community to make zero effort to improve questions rather than closing. We expect better of ourselves than that.

Comment: @Nij can you describe what a low-quality answer *that actually answers this question* would look like? The problem is pretty constrained, after all; if the issue is that it's "syntactically" a forbidden rec question & the actual problem I described doesn't matter, that probably would have been a simple edit. But according to the meta answer this question seems ok, which means there's more that isn't clearly articulated there and I don't know what else you want. Is it thus any wonder that I'm reluctant to climb your learning curve when I have a solution & nobody offered help before I asked?

Comment: "Here's a type of game, which of them can be played really quickly?" **and** "here's a group of games, how can I make any/all of them faster?" are still very broad, even with the implicit requirement that they support newbie players, and you're asking both. It wouldn't matter whether low-quality answers were relevant or helpful, the very fact that they'd be posted in the first place is the problem. So, until such time as the question itself can define narrowly what a **good** answer looks like, so one above any possible other could be reasonably picked as best, it should remain closed.

Comment: I understand the term "gateway game" to mean "a representative member of its class that plays well and entices new gamers to play more games of that type". Is that not the common understanding on this site @Nij? But eh, I'm not going to argue w/you about it; you see a broad unanswerable question & I don't. The way this question played out was disappointing and didn't leave me inclined to guess my way to something that would comply with your expectations. I just came here to solve a problem; I didn't get the reception I expected, but I did get an answer and y'all don't want my question, so meh.

Comment: If this were just about the house rules (i.e. no existing policy against the question), I would fight pretty hard against a "too broad" closure. It's a well-defined problem. We really need to not get stuck in this mindset that anything other than a single obviously correct answer is too broad. For the recommendation part, I don't see it as much more broad, and the only issue is that it's against an established policy - one which throws out good questions like this one along with bad questions like many we used to see. So... if y'all wanna meta, go for it, but let's not exaggerate the issues.

Comment: And: I am *not* going to delete any comments here; I'll migrate to chat if it gets too long, but this is hardly the most egregious answer-in-comments I've ever seen, and every comment contains parts that are relevant to the meta/scope discussion, so I couldn't really snip out an answer without having to edit others' comments, which is a can of worms. (And I don't think insisting on strict rules adherence is really going to get us anywhere on this specific case anyway.)